# Python 2.6 automatically turns variables within a function definition global under certain circumstances? Why?

Tags: python, debugging, global-variables, issue-tracking, local-variables

I am absolutely dumbfounded by why the following is happening:

Here is my code:

---

```
def add_one(array):

    new_array = array
    length = len(array)

    for i in range(length):

        new_array[i] = new_array[i]+1


    return new_array

x = [1,2,3,4,5];
y = add_one(x)

print x

print y
```

---

Here are the results:

```
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]

[2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
```

---

I do not understand why x is changed.

My speculations:
Somehow x is given as a global variable to the function add_one. I included 'new_array = array' so that if array was somehow the global variable x, x would not be changed. However, somehow new_array also became the global variable x when 'new_array = array' was executed. I wrote an alternate version of the function add_one which did not give me issues:

---

```
def add_one(array):

    new_array = []
    length = len(array)

    for i in range(length):
        new_array.append(array[i]+1)
```

---

It seems that if a local variable (that is a array) is edited by it's index within a function, it turns global with respect to the global variable that was taken as an input for that function?

I have no idea what is going on. Any explanations would be highly appreciated.

Comment: Scoping in Python is sometimes not as clean as some might expect, but it's not **that** weird ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Nothing is made global for obscure readons. `array` is still a perfectly normal local variable. But it's a reference, as everything in Python (well, every name at least) is a reference:

- `add_one(x)` passes a reference (not like a reference in e.g. C++, more like a pointer - if either of that means anything to you) to `x` to `add_one`
- `new_array = array` will just copy that reference
- No copying happening, all these names point to the same object!

That means that calling a method on `array` in `add_one` modified the very same object `x` of the caller refers to - re-assigning `array` (`array = []`) will just overwrite the local copy of the reference and not affect other variables referring to the same object (after all, it's quite possible that there is no such variable!), but member or item assignment (e.g. `new_array[i] = ...`) is basically a method call and *will* modify the object.

Generally, the easiest way to generate a new list from an existing one with some pattern of modification applied to each element and optionally some filtering is using a list comprehension. `[x + 1 for x array]` in this example.

Comment: Thank you! This clarified my confusion totally.

Comment: I get what you said, but are arrays treated different? For example:

Comment: def add(num):
    num[0]=num[0]+1

x=[1]

add(x); print x

Comment: def add(num):
    num=num+1

x=1

add(x); print x

Comment: in the two pieces of code above, one changes the value of x, while the other doesn't. (When x is an array it is changed).

Comment: (Perhaps you should read again. The following explanation is already contained in the answer.) Lists are not different, they're objects as everything else. What *is* different is item assignment vs assignment of a variable. Item assignment (`num[0] = ...`) is a method call so it modifies (or, to nitpick: can modify; although not doing anything upon item assignment is madness) the object. Overwriting a plain variable name (`num = ...`) doesn't and can't. Full stop, new paragraph.

Comment: Ahh, I see now. Thank you (both delnan and Mark Ransom and everyone else) for the clarification. Much appreciated - John

Answer (score 6):

When you say `new_array = array`, you're not making a copy of the array, you're simply making another name for the array. Both names still apply to the same array.

To make a copy the simplest way is to use slicing: `new_array = array[:]`

Comment: This works great. However, why is array even treated as a global variable in the first place?

Comment: @John, it's not global. You passed it into the function, and the function modified it. You didn't *think* you were modifying it because you were using a different name.

Answer (score 1):

On your third line you set y to x.

```
new_array = array
```

Answer (score 0):

This line is the crucial one:

```
new_array = array
```

You have to see `new_array` not as a new variable, but as a new name for the variable (object) which already has the name `array`.

Comment: @delnan: Not sure why you say that. My answer is not as thorough as yours but the point that `new_array` is just a "name" or "reference" to the same object is the crucial thing, isn't it?

Comment: @delnan: I don't see any motive for downvoting this answer as well. It is short, suscitn and correct. One might not have motives to  vote for it, but thre is nothing wrong with it.

Comment: @jsbueno: Especially the original version not shown in the edit history (very quick edits aren't recorded) basically just said "this line is causing this problem" without doing so much as hinting to any of the knowledge required to understand why. This version is slightly better, but I think it's still obvious that OP required some more explanation why this matters.

Comment: @delnan: You are right, I think I hit "Post Answer" with only the first two lines at first. Then, added the two (more) lines.